# How can I set a Heroku config var to a JSON value?

Tags: json, heroku, environment-variables

I want to use a JSON value as a environment variable with `heroku config:set`.

But if I run this command:

```
heroku config:set FOO_JSON={"abc":"bcd","cde":"def" ... }
```

all `"` are removed like this:

```
FOO_JSON={abc:bcd,cde:def ... }
```

and I get a parse error.

How can I use JSON in Heroku's environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku will remove the first and last `"` but that is fine, I had similar issue recently.
When you fetch the variable in your codebase, it will be wrapped with string quotations back so you can successfully `JSON.parse(process.env.VARIABLE)`

Example. I had a list of some banned users in my local `.env`

```
BANLIST = '["abdu","yak","jek","tosch","krek"]'
```

So, I can simply set

```
heroku config:set BANLIST='["abdu","yak","jek","tosch","krek"]'
```

or

```
heroku config:set BANLIST=["abdu","yak","jek","tosch","krek"]
```

Both of them will result to `["abdu","yak","jek","tosch","krek"]`.

So, when you fetch it back with `JSON.parse(process.env.BANLIST)`, you will get the appropriate array output.

Warning: If you set the config variable wrapped with `'` or `"` with heroku GUI interface, it will not set at all, so just put your array or object JSON without wrapping it with either of those

Comment: "If you set the config variable wrapped with ' or " with heroku GUI interface, it will not set at all", that's funny I just spent the past hour debugging everything but that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how your shell processes quotes. Wrap the whole thing in single quotes:

```
heroku config:set FOO_JSON='{"abc":"bcd","cde":"def" ... }'
```

Comment: thenk you. but it doesn't work.
result is `FOO_JSON: '{abc:bcd,cde:def}'`

Comment: What operating system and shell are you using?

Comment: I use windows10 cmd

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should still work, @invalid. How are you using the value so it gives you an error?

Comment: I use value like this  
`const obj = JSON.parse(process.env.FOO_JSON)`  
it work fine on local, but not on heroku. I get error :  
`unexpected token a`  
so I check environment variable on both local and heroku.  
local : `FOO_JSON={"abc":"bcd"}`  
heroku : `FOO_JSON={abc:bcd}`  
If I set env by this commend : 
`heroku config:set FOO_JSON='{"abc":"bcd"}'`
then content of FOO_JSON on heroku was like this :  
`'{abc:bcd}'`

Comment: What does "it works fine on local" mean? How are you setting the variable locally? Are you running your code via `heroku local`, or something else?

Comment: `It wowrks fine` means success JSON.parse(process.env.FOO_JSON).    I set variable with dotenv locally.    I am sorry in confusing expressions, but I'm not using `heroku local`. I just run `npm run` in local (this is Express.js project).    And 
escaping doublequorts solve this problem a while ago `FOO_JSON={\"abc\":\"bcd\"}`.  But the reason why `FOO_JSON='{"abc":"bcd"}'` doesn't work is still unclear.

Comment: this works on a Mac, but not in Git Bash on Windows

Comment: Related question, focusing on Git Bash in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859583/how-to-set-json-object-as-heroku-environment-variable-on-git-bash